# How to use magento ImportExport module in your custom module

Tags: module, magento-1, importexport

For my module I need to insert data that has nothing to do with magento products or categories. It is just a list of stores, addresses and coordinates, so I guess it could be a separate table inside the db. I'm stuck and don't know how to start as there is little information about this.

I found this useful presentation http://netzarbeiter.com/media/MagentoImagine/ImportExport.pdf that talks about 
`Mage_ImportExport_Adminhtml_ImportController` and `Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import`, but I need slightly more information about how to use it.

Basically, I think it should be something simple as this, but developed in an OOP magento way...

```
$file = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

$handle = fopen($file, "r");

while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE){

    $latitude = $data[0];
    $longitude = $data[1];

    $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO table_name (latitude,longitude) VALUES ('".$latitude."','".$longitude."')");

}
```

I know it is a long shot, but maybe there is somebody here with experience at this and can provide directions...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be a good start to google for "Avs_FastSimpleImport" it is an extension which extends ImportExport. Only for products but still a good start. And Andreas gave lots and lots of talks and wrote blog posts about it.